# How to make Firefox use a proxy server for localhost connections

Tags: firefox, ssh, proxy

I have a SOCKS proxy forwarding port 9999 on my local machine to a remote development server. I use that proxy connection with Firefox so that I can access the dev server's network, but I also want to be able to forward localhost connections in Firefox to the remote server's `localhost` to connect to various services running there. I have removed `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` from the "No proxy for" setting and it still doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to change another setting, in addition to removing `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` from the "No proxy for" box: set `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` to `true` in about:config.

This was changed recently. Source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581