# How to Change IP address of [ ::1 ] in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to Recode the test Script of VPN accessed Website and for that i am using JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and start connection by using the localhost but by analysis i monitor that JMeter send request and in Remote server section it send [::1]:Port this value so please help me how to change this method and share Remote IP in Remote Address section

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch JMeter to use [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) [localhost loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution) - 127.0.0.1 you need to add the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

More information:

- [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

You will also need to configure the browser to not to bypass proxy for local addresses, i.e. for Firefox you need to set [`network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` option to `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419408/how-to-make-firefox-use-a-proxy-server-for-localhost-connections)

Comment: Check this Image it shows when i am sending request to access the web page due to proxy confirmation Browser send [::1]:80 as IP address https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq03H.png