# Unbale to record JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record sample web application using JMeter and unable to record the events even after making necessary proxy settings and importing JMeter root CA certificate.

Why events are not recording and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure to start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Then make sure to import JMeter's certificate into your browser (the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter's proxy). See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [JMeter User Manual entry on the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder for more details](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
3. Make sure that the proxy is being used for HTTPS as well

   [image]
4. If you're using Firefox you will need to set [`network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419408/how-to-make-firefox-use-a-proxy-server-for-localhost-connections) setting to `true`, type about:config in the URL string, look for this setting and amend the value
5. Just in case [clear your browsing history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox)as you might face issues with certificates pinning and HSTS

Alternatively just go for [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Applied above changes and tried recording but getting below error
Error code: SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

This website might not support the TLS 1.2 protocol, which is the minimum version supported by Firefox.