# Jmeter Test steps recorder is not saving the steps after stop the record

Tags: jmeter

I know that maybe this question is duplicated, but I haven't find the solution in other questions.
I have Jmeter 5.5, and I added new test plan with a Https test script recorder and a thread group and under it I added a recording controller.

In the test script recorder I set the port number equal to 8080, and I added the certificate to the Firefox browser.
[image: Jmeter Screen]

In the Firefox browser I added proxy setting as below
[image: Firefox proxy setting]

But when I click start in jmeter then start doing the steps in the browser and after that click stop in Jmeter nothing is listed under recording controller.
So my question is: Is there any problem with my setting, is there any missed steps?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox by default doesn't use proxy for `localhost`, you will need to

1. open `about:config` in the URL
2. look for `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` property
3. set it to `true`

[image]

More information: [How to make Firefox use a proxy server for localhost connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419408/how-to-make-firefox-use-a-proxy-server-for-localhost-connections)

In addition I would recommend using [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions), it comes up with a "good" configuration when it comes to recording test plan setup, filtering embedded and external resources and so on.

Also be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T I try to use Recoding controller it is worked for me, now I can see the steps under recoding controller